# how do $filter() work internally in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have an array of objects `searchArr`. And another array of objects `arr`.

```
searchArr = [{id: 36, user_id: "oulFlPx9Ho3U",account_number: "orsV5zWHquBX_orCvEx4YdQxP_1903", bank_name: "BANK1TEST"}]

arr = [{bank_name: "BANK1TEST", org_id: "orsV5zWHquBX", currency: "USD", account_number: "orsV5zWHquBX_orCvEx4YdQxP_1903", id: "baccD82Lu7rQ0y"}, {bank_name: "BANK1TEST", org_id: "orsV5zWHquBX", currency: "USD" account_number: "orsV5zWHquBX_orCvEx4YdQxP_1", id: "baccIRmnWaEiJm"}]
```

I want to filter all the data which has same name and phone number on `searchArr` and `arr`.
So I write this code inside the `arr.foreach(ar)`:

```
var foo = $filter('filter')(searchArr, {account_number: ar.account_number, bank_name: ar.bank_name})
```

However, if I print out the value of the result it gets the value `[{id: 36, user_id: "oulFlPx9Ho3U",account_number: "orsV5zWHquBX_orCvEx4YdQxP_1903", bank_name: "BANK1TEST"}]` printed twice which means it is not filtering out exactly.

On the contrary, if I use this piece of code, it works perfectly:

```
var foo = searchArr.filter(function (bar) {
   return bar.account_number === ar.account_number && bar.bank_name === ar.bank_name;
});
```

This returns only one entry. I think both of this should be working correctly.

Edit:
Question: Does $filter works as contains()? I mean i had account_number that I was trying to filter is `orsV5zWHquBX_orCvEx4YdQxP_1903` and the one it filtered is `orsV5zWHquBX_orCvEx4YdQxP_1`.

Comment: So the difference is just the object inside of the array, instead of just the object, right?

Comment: If you have a look at the filter documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter it returns the results as a new array, not a single object

Comment: yes. it will return the result as the array of objects only. In my case, it should've returned only for one value of `arr` but it's returning for both although `account_number` is different .